# Showing $\min_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda| \le \vert y^\ast \Sigma y \vert \le \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda|$ $\forall y$ with unit norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

### Problem

Suppose $A$ is $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix, and unitarily diagonalized as follows

$$
A = U\Sigma U^\ast
$$

where $\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues and $U$ is the matrix of orthonormal eigenvectors.

> Show, for $\forall y$ such that $\Vert y \Vert_2 = 1$,
>
> $$\min_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda| \le \vert y^\ast \Sigma y \vert \le \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda|$$
>
> where $\sigma(A)$ denotes the set of all eigenvalues of $A$.

---

### Try

Let $u_1, \cdots, u_n$ be the columns of $U$. Then

$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i
$$

with $\sum_i a_i^2 = 1$. Thus

$$
\vert y^\ast \Sigma y \vert = \vert \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2   \lambda_i \vert
$$

but I'm not sure we can say

$$\min_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda| \le \vert \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2   \lambda_i \vert \le \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda|$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write $\sum_i|a_i|^2=1$ and $|y^\ast \Sigma y|=\left|\sum_i|a_i|^2\lambda_i\right|$ rather than $\sum_ia_i^2=1$ and
$|y^\ast \Sigma y|=\left|\sum_ia_i^2\lambda_i\right|$. The inequality
$$
\min_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|\lambda|\le|y^\ast\Sigma y|
$$
is wrong, as seen from the counterexample $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$ and $y^\ast=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$. However, the other inequality does hold, because
$$
|y^\ast\Sigma y|=\left|\sum_i|a_i|^2\lambda_i\right|\le\sum_i|a_i|^2|\lambda_i|\le\sum_i|a_i|^2\max_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|\lambda|=\max_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|\lambda|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^T \Sigma y = \sum_{i,j} y_iy_j\lambda_i\delta_{ij}=\sum_{i}\lambda_i y_iy_i$$

We have,

$$\lambda_{min}\sum_{i} y_iy_i \leq \sum_{i}\lambda_i y_iy_i \leq \lambda_{max}\sum_{i} y_iy_i$$

Since $y$ has unit norm $\sum_i y_iy_i=1$. Therefore,

$$min_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda \leq y^T \Sigma y  \leq max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda$$

This inequality is true. However, take the mod and only the upper bound remains true. The given question is wrong.